# What happen if we commit something that is already in the remote repo

Tags: git, github, repository

I corrected a spelling mistake and committed my local changes but that change was already done by somebody and pushed to remote repository. So my commit is not showing in the Log/History in Source Tree as a commit. There is not conflict as well. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Are you using a client or committing by command line? It would help if you provide the executed commands and the output, or at least a screen capture if you're using a client.

Comment: I used client (Source Tree) and I did not took a screenshot when it was committing. I just want to know above scenario is possible or not.

Comment: What does "[I] committed to remote repository" mean? Git commits happen locally; the way to get a commit onto your remote is to `push` it.

Comment: I commit my local changes in order to get a pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the scenario was like this.
you corrected the misspelling and commit it to your local repository. when you wanted to push to the remote repository you noticed there were changes that you have to pull first. so you have pulled the changes and it was automatically merged with your commit and every thing were fine.

I think it is possible to not have conflict because of 'recursive' strategy.
I am not sure about that.
[git merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies)

Comment: Ok but why isn't it displaying in the source tree Log/History tab as a commit. It is supposed to display any small change that we commited with the person who commit it and the comment regarding the commit right?

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon your commit wasn't pushed and probably it was discarded by SourceTree because the same change was already made on the repo.